# How to check status login and redirect to dashboard in Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I created two pages: `<login>` and `<dashboard>`. In login form I create `userInput and passwordInput` and button submit. When the user type and click into button submit. When app start ,how to check if user logined to app, it will redirect to `<dashboard>` and if user have not login to app, it will redirect to login? Thanks you for support

Comment: Normally one would store an access token in local storage or cookies to determine if the user is logged in or not. To have role based re direct in your app, you can make use of Outlet from react-router-dom version 6.

Comment: thanks you ! i'm learning and i get stuck with redux toolkit : slice..so don't know how to put it code `localStorage.setitem(...)`? @Arpit

Comment: I haven't used redux toolkit so I wouldn't know. To store in local storage, you have to do it like this:  JSON.stringify(localStorage.setIem('token'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check with your token in cookies or local storage with the following database users**

```
export default function route(){
```

if a user exists in your DB then set validation true or either false

```
let validation=localStorage.getItem("token");

if(validation){

return(<Dashboard/>)

}
else{
return(<Login/>)
}
```